# Android Chromium WebView Crash

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I have an app which is running on an Android 5.1.1 Device. The app has one webview (48.0.2564.106) which stays 24/7. Sometimes the app crashes because the chromium webview has an uncaught exception. The newest version of the webview has the same crash.
The Chrome Browser app has the same issue but the app dont crash and shows a error page.

Can i register an uncaught exceptionhandler for the webview and caught the crashes without an app crash?

Are there other solutions for this problem?

**Added Crash report**:

```
    03-31 05:55:51.853 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
    03-31 05:55:51.853 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: V WebView:50.0.2661.49
    03-31 05:55:51.869 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: O A arm 08 armv7l hardkernel/cm_odroidxu3/odroidxu3:5.1.1/LMY49F/00799280db:userdebug/test-keys
    03-31 05:55:51.869 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.0|ARM|Mali-T628
    03-31 05:55:51.873 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S 0 A01CED30 A01CE000 00001000
    03-31 05:55:51.894 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE000 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.895 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE180 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.896 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE300 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.897 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE480 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.898 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE600 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.899 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE780 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.900 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CE900 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.901 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CEA80 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B8ED1CA06E000000B8ED1CA007D7E5B60000000000000000020000009434D5AEB8ED1CA06E00000        0B8ED1CA06E000000020000009434D5AE00000000000000002F000000F8EB1CA0DB4D85AA038220C008EC1CA008EC1CA0
    03-31 05:55:51.902 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CEC00 68706B9700E06A97F8706B970090779700000000F8706B97B0706B97C08F7797D8706B9701B887AA8C10BF685DBB87AA4010BF6800000000349FE99C00000000C69FFC56571E2E20C052D0AE8834D5AEC0A7F46D90A7F46D5877D5A        E0100000068ED1CA01BE787AA5877D5AE5477D5AE40AD5A9740CF6B975877D5AE27C387AA5877D5AE00D06C97000000005877D5AE9D9E8AAA759E8AAA00000000000000001C15866B9B9E8AAA1815866B0000000020608E6BF8EC1CA00100000020608E6B0000000000000000DC88D5AE0100000068ED1CA08FA        887AAB8ED1CA06E000000FEFFFFFFDC88D5AEE8E9D8AE20608E6B0000000000000000FEFFFFFF000000007484D5AE0000000019A887AA00000000DC88D5AE0100000068ED1CA0A7B087AA00000000FFFFFFFF00BEC4AE904F4D6DE888D5AE300F45970030D5AEE088D5AEB8ED1CA0FFC99A3B509FD5AE0000000        000CA9A3B7484D5AE68ED1CA03CA156AB0089D5AEDC88D5AEC69FFC56942C2A20FFFFFFFF00BEC4AE40BEC4AE00BEC4AE
    03-31 05:55:51.903 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad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
    03-31 05:55:51.904 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: S A01CEF00 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    03-31 05:55:51.904 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad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
    03-31 05:55:51.911 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6FDE000 00000000 00003000 F91F01F0880541A2B69E70DB92DCA6C30 app_process32
    03-31 05:55:51.912 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M 72EA1000 01B95000 01601000 000000000000000000000000000000000 system@framework@boot.oat
    03-31 05:55:51.912 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M 9E52E000 00143000 0011E000 000000000000000000000000000000000 data@app@com.google.android.webview-1@base.apk@classes.dex
    03-31 05:55:51.914 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M A14CA000 00000000 00002000 F786FA54B1844430370450775E3839AD0 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
    03-31 05:55:51.917 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M A1AF0000 00000000 00001000 0069892A6B18E36F077062E2B38562400 libion.so
    03-31 05:55:51.919 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M A1AF3000 00000000 00003000 907D136486D9579E878D40BBE7F4119F0 gralloc.exynos5.so
    03-31 05:55:51.922 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M A2AF1000 008CC000 006F5000 000000000000000000000000000000000 data@app@com.example.android.webview-1@base.apk@classes.dex
    03-31 05:55:51.923 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M A41E7000 00000000 01ECF000 D5B9C75BB7032AE7AFDB61BEBDE454A60 libwebviewchromium.so
    03-31 05:55:51.926 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AA5E7000 00000000 00001000 92B6D9805AAF5A77849ECC69200A5D2E0 libwebviewchromium_loader.so
    03-31 05:55:51.928 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AA5EA000 00000000 00001000 8FF5949AE957364C270D0F448DAD4FE20 libjnigraphics.so
    03-31 05:55:51.930 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AA5EE000 00000000 00005000 E127AEA15C122B0FF8746B0B5E6AEA900 libcompiler_rt.so
    03-31 05:55:51.933 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AA5F5000 00000000 0000D000 E4CEF5EDFBB5994F920E12960C27E0BC0 libandroid.so
    03-31 05:55:51.939 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AA606000 00000000 00F22000 0B2A21248CFB6E8959522B8FF1662D950 libGLES_mali.so
    03-31 05:55:51.946 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC465000 00000000 00016000 423418A5A80B9CF1C08953AD0BCC31C10 libjavacrypto.so
    03-31 05:55:51.947 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC47D000 00000000 00002000 B472CADC2448C211F1E320D88D27B5420 libemoji.so
    03-31 05:55:51.948 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC481000 00000000 00007000 845CCEA67E2BC12F4E227C6A39A0DCD80 librs_jni.so
    03-31 05:55:51.949 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC48B000 00000000 00004000 8C05B27FF35398D83E35148CDD6D4E750 libaudioeffect_jni.so
    03-31 05:55:51.954 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC491000 00000000 00002000 CD81F3A45DFAE6BB5989B4F79AF751180 libsoundpool.so
    03-31 05:55:51.957 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC495000 00000000 00003000 E49B1043B44BE38829C73278C9C9BE630 libexynosscaler.so
    03-31 05:55:51.960 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC49A000 00000000 00009000 1A5D560EB4BFF31623DD2C73F6118AFA0 libMcClient.so
    03-31 05:55:51.963 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4A5000 00000000 00001000 E9139A8ED4927A4651DC7E83A9F294280 libion_exynos.so
    03-31 05:55:51.964 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4A8000 00000000 00007000 85BEB3A07FB74C2BE7A2125ACF3EFF970 libexynosgscaler.so
    03-31 05:55:51.972 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4B2000 00000000 00001000 F0E2E019A67337A6108AF214B680998E0 libmpp.so
    03-31 05:55:51.973 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4B5000 00000000 00002000 8790C261666B1AC34EB1481037136FB70 libhwcutilsmodule.so
    03-31 05:55:51.975 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4B9000 00000000 00004000 B6BA34CE6506472ADA7A04E6B290D0500 libhwcutils.so
    03-31 05:55:51.978 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4BF000 00000000 00004000 0A13F611BB14FC32A7E8C70F0A9FC6930 libdisplay.so
    03-31 05:55:51.981 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4C5000 00000000 00002000 DE2715E947441F70F32D44A394F1D28F0 libexynosutils.so
    03-31 05:55:51.982 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4C9000 00000000 00005000 F93C0BAFA79B11A37F58319831A64E230 libhdmi.so
    03-31 05:55:51.995 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4D0000 00000000 00005000 29412375E50534525602DEFBBA0083430 libexynosv4l2.so
    03-31 05:55:51.997 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4D7000 00000000 00018000 F5966599665F4B070B7B57DAE5DBA86F0 libvorbisidec.so
    03-31 05:55:52.002 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4F1000 00000000 00002000 9D3A1EEE172AFB35E2663261B36F7D400 libstagefright_yuv.so
    03-31 05:55:52.006 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC4F5000 00000000 0001E000 C07676D1AD635D9B5F43E8D438B313950 libstagefright_omx.so
    03-31 05:55:52.017 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC516000 00000000 00001000 E11DA546CE9E08D1D647E8E1135DAD810 libstagefright_enc_common.so
    03-31 05:55:52.021 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC519000 00000000 00005000 741CD0CBF5589F8EDBD02FD7023550580 libstagefright_avc_common.so
    03-31 05:55:52.028 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC521000 00000000 00038000 E5C670B735242BF581AAFAC94791DAAD0 libopus.so
    03-31 05:55:52.032 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC55B000 00000000 00008000 88F95E0B686F366CEC701A57A405FE6B0 libExynosHWCService.so
    03-31 05:55:52.034 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC566000 00000000 0000C000 D791A978CC1F875366C3FDE9B33194060 libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
    03-31 05:55:52.040 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC574000 00000000 00120000 1EA0682A50686B87B2D92BD1B3BCC1C40 libstagefright.so
    03-31 05:55:52.044 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC69C000 00000000 00012000 A5D6C11480F11BD012CFA5F9D9C3F3BD0 libmtp.so
    03-31 05:55:52.045 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC6B0000 00000000 00009000 C2A60AD5A4D7D4D6751EAB71E4B978460 libjhead.so
    03-31 05:55:52.046 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC6BC000 00000000 0001F000 F194101DF9559E0FC114F8C8311A0CC20 libexif.so
    03-31 05:55:52.061 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AC6E8000 00000000 00038000 A2AC7BD6C0B9E05401CA1ADE9FCB77190 libmedia_jni.so
    03-31 05:55:52.068 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M AF08D000 00000000 00001000 17DD1298959FF781D22FFBFA1EE68F280 memtrack.exynos5.so
    03-31 05:55:52.073 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B06BE000 00000000 00034000 EBAB7DCB6D5F8B481FE88A667C72E0C20 libjavacore.so
    03-31 05:55:52.074 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B502A000 00000000 00006000 F1305543FBF640FB1847C8D1284F78F60 libbacktrace_libc++.so
    03-31 05:55:52.095 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5032000 00000000 002FF000 B80C9B40ABB9D8BE618868B157E04C400 libart.so
    03-31 05:55:52.097 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B535E000 00000000 00003000 D34C23E89E0324AD7350F8E43B0F05A10 libpowermanager.so
    03-31 05:55:52.099 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5363000 00000000 0000B000 E2DD6FCC6A85AF2204C3DD01BB5505510 libcommon_time_client.so
    03-31 05:55:52.099 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5372000 00000000 0003B000 8AABB758BF07454F7EA546AA313032D80 libbcinfo.so
    03-31 05:55:52.099 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B53AF000 00000000 00021000 9D8DC2FF4FD98A1921B287CB333B0A6A0 libbcc.so
    03-31 05:55:52.099 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B53F2000 00000000 008C4000 D31387E4AA2C2914F9212F106219D19B0 libLLVM.so
    03-31 05:55:52.100 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5CFD000 00000000 00002000 7A80CF6FADF6A3E8B908CC78ED49A6960 libunwind-ptrace.so
    03-31 05:55:52.100 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5D01000 00000000 0000C000 FEC52DCEA9703BC3D04786B7558687FF0 libunwind.so
    03-31 05:55:52.100 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5D55000 00000000 00005000 3874D35A672DF926049632908E3F44990 libgccdemangle.so
    03-31 05:55:52.102 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5D5C000 00000000 00010000 1ED726B29E92DEC8EA3197FAED4636470 libpcre.so
    03-31 05:55:52.102 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5D6E000 00000000 00087000 5E0A90160446DDFDE3BC9FA8E47AFFAA0 libc++.so
    03-31 05:55:52.102 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5DFB000 00000000 00024000 6B5DD43D82150C454911AF75E073C4640 libpng.so
    03-31 05:55:52.113 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5E21000 00000000 00057000 655CEB4AAD23E6191010184F043F4CE10 libft2.so
    03-31 05:55:52.116 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5E7D000 00000000 00014000 04AB93E5DB7D4B95BC764FD1EB5413FE0 libstagefright_foundation.so
    03-31 05:55:52.119 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5E93000 00000000 00007000 DAD388CD23A163A1A850D5E8E3971F6A0 libnbaio.so
    03-31 05:55:52.132 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5E9C000 00000000 00004000 E3AE8BE37EE0B813F539936AB3929DEB0 libgabi++.so
    03-31 05:55:52.133 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5EA2000 00000000 0001B000 C4D7F0E34D03835243FC9583AC40DF8D0 libRScpp.so
    03-31 05:55:52.133 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5EBF000 00000000 00033000 A3233004C3F58A0C4489A4E441906F190 libRS.so
    03-31 05:55:52.141 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5EF4000 00000000 00003000 26CD5350496C4B0C3238F3ED9892DB410 libwpa_client.so
    03-31 05:55:52.143 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5EF9000 00000000 00001000 2D9083CB8C22C02E1412DA13B1CA43AE0 libsync.so
    03-31 05:55:52.149 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5EFC000 00000000 00004000 AC1D7BAE26791BE91E8BCCB199F3926F0 libspeexresampler.so
    03-31 05:55:52.157 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5F02000 00000000 00068000 B6A5A6D1BD503AC9D8218C47DB15CE8F0 libGLES_trace.so
    03-31 05:55:52.159 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5F6C000 00000000 00006000 BCAB4FA0EABE6F75503A4186AF09AC050 libbacktrace.so
    03-31 05:55:52.165 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5F74000 00000000 00018000 03AD8D1D4EBAA7AEEB016E971EDBB3AE0 libz.so
    03-31 05:55:52.169 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5F8E000 00000000 00002000 C88FD942703CD0910236DC719AB36EF90 libusbhost.so
    03-31 05:55:52.172 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5F93000 00000000 0000A000 5A8A09DF85802436D259D1F54D40AD660 libui.so
    03-31 05:55:52.174 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5F9F000 00000000 00033000 2EB439F33DB4650FE42FAAA99395E65F0 libstlport.so
    03-31 05:55:52.174 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B5FD5000 00000000 0003A000 B2A7C1EAE2BFBD8B512F52C550D03BA70 libssl.so
    03-31 05:55:52.191 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6014000 00000000 0005D000 D366CCABBFDC2ACFAA335C09398BB9370 libsqlite.so
    03-31 05:55:52.197 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6074000 00000000 0000A000 FEEFBB918616C9664F948E273A3A03EF0 libsoundtrigger.so
    03-31 05:55:52.204 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6082000 00000000 0004E000 6EBD68D265DA3C2168C5F7A923284D4C0 libsonivox.so
    03-31 05:55:52.210 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B60D7000 00000000 001FB000 72491A2BE701A6E2612A0878A8BD3AC70 libskia.so
    03-31 05:55:52.212 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B62EB000 00000000 0000C000 120A6F36FB9BF8CEC92AE73A594170130 libselinux.so
    03-31 05:55:52.214 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B62F9000 00000000 00002000 4E6C8C876BA563C3C4B0B3BA562093920 libprocessgroup.so
    03-31 05:55:52.226 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B62FD000 00000000 00439000 83C530EBE395DB5C15F9E1A6BAF1B5740 libpdfium.so
    03-31 05:55:52.228 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6748000 00000000 00005000 FE618961FF21EA63F64F394F9E013C410 libnetutils.so
    03-31 05:55:52.228 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B674F000 00000000 00002000 495A7C47952A09509BE1A7C105A50EF20 libnetd_client.so
    03-31 05:55:52.237 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6754000 00000000 00004000 6D8792E6DBBC9786154F651A05029FCB0 libnativehelper.so
    03-31 05:55:52.239 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B675A000 00000000 00002000 287CFEAD48FDE609382A481FD2022B0F0 libnativebridge.so
    03-31 05:55:52.241 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B675F000 00000000 00009000 0A0BBB9F855C06447D8E63B23F8965E80 libminikin.so
    03-31 05:55:52.246 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B676A000 00000000 00001000 CCA8BE0D07D24523C8D02FEE5F724EA70 libmemtrack.so
    03-31 05:55:52.255 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B676D000 00000000 0007F000 44E82C3779ACF09B99081692D9BC27D30 libmedia.so
    03-31 05:55:52.268 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6805000 00000000 00030000 89A474B3CCE30E155303C12622AEECFA0 libjpeg.so
    03-31 05:55:52.276 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6837000 00000000 00036000 C621058819B7DEC2E2418D2EB2BB6B060 libinputflinger.so
    03-31 05:55:52.277 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6870000 00000000 00016000 04C80C73C532595C3B4FD4ADB80057330 libinput.so
    03-31 05:55:52.278 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B688A000 00000000 0000B000 438B28EF00342054E26A5744FB228F250 libimg_utils.so
    03-31 05:55:52.279 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6898000 00000000 000FD000 19B0C7CD6FAFFD434FEA243673EA25130 libicuuc.so
    03-31 05:55:52.281 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B69A3000 00000000 0014F000 23F1A0622B97B553871971130E2981050 libicui18n.so
    03-31 05:55:52.283 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6AFB000 00000000 00047000 9B76F1ACAC32AE62C18A812B3DF5DF640 libhwui.so
    03-31 05:55:52.293 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B47000 00000000 00046000 ACA51CBC23D1439DDCF93DF6697D090D0 libharfbuzz_ng.so
    03-31 05:55:52.293 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B8F000 00000000 00005000 E3851ACF3D978D1FEDA5216A34669EBC0 libhardware_legacy.so
    03-31 05:55:52.294 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B97000 00000000 00001000 74BDE5859537C5E7870D0EAFCD264B590 libhardware.so
    03-31 05:55:52.297 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B9A000 00000000 00040000 2229301E82C2F8729FE83C137D9F1E7E0 libgui.so
    03-31 05:55:52.300 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6BE6000 00000000 00014000 BE487D5116BB4AF53060EBDC4CBCBED50 libexpat.so
    03-31 05:55:52.302 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6BFD000 00000000 00017000 195B37AA3D6654C8CB30DB89473D6F4E0 libdrmframework.so
    03-31 05:55:52.302 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C18000 00000000 000E3000 A3B732DCDEAAA0D5C308E604F03AC7BA0 libcrypto.so
    03-31 05:55:52.305 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D10000 00000000 00006000 FD57833F6EB1C9D6CF3B9E1E05329E950 libcamera_metadata.so
    03-31 05:55:52.307 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D18000 00000000 0002E000 EC0D358B3D8C0E0A82F0B27250421B6C0 libcamera_client.so
    03-31 05:55:52.324 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D50000 00000000 00004000 C51E7EC90A302DA7F15A919CF3BA46D80 libaudioutils.so
    03-31 05:55:52.327 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D56000 00000000 00023000 8E7FA554F3BCB62C9DD54DC54B2960A70 libandroidfw.so
    03-31 05:55:52.427 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D7B000 00000000 00009000 E2F67EE50006FD0ED1482E1463C5CCFF0 libGLESv2.so
    03-31 05:55:52.437 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D87000 00000000 00005000 EFE6ADDAF48E0BCED48FF0E60558C2F60 libGLESv1_CM.so
    03-31 05:55:52.438 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D8E000 00000000 00002000 DE56AF21D1810CB9F5D59132F2B573690 libETC1.so
    03-31 05:55:52.442 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D92000 00000000 0005D000 93F74A59437E113252066F4768CFEEFE0 libEGL.so
    03-31 05:55:52.447 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6DFE000 00000000 00014000 4999CBF09935744F68862E21CD4D56630 libutils.so
    03-31 05:55:52.449 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6E14000 00000000 00002000 DFD777ACF34CBD2037A5FC4C5DDFC1430 libstdc++.so
    03-31 05:55:52.458 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6E18000 00000000 0001B000 749BDF3D04D27C1348A2B25FC55D49B10 libm.so
    03-31 05:55:52.459 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6E35000 00000000 00005000 17DAF2C35439C0FCB2AFF12EDF73DBAB0 liblog.so
    03-31 05:55:52.460 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6E3C000 00000000 0000B000 006AEA2A756FF4905584F4E4A10BC82F0 libcutils.so
    03-31 05:55:52.469 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6E49000 00000000 00063000 C51DA9B0346DEC997081BBB631FE4CBA0 libc.so
    03-31 05:55:52.470 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6EBB000 00000000 00025000 AF9A35CC2340565B9A757A4A940816770 libbinder.so
    03-31 05:55:52.480 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6EE8000 00000000 000CE000 886F1D7A0E51021EC09FB7483FE85E150 libandroid_runtime.so
    03-31 05:55:52.480 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6FC4000 00000000 00001000 133BEE27C6351072BEF5780E5368857F0 libsigchain.so
    03-31 05:55:52.480 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: M B6FCD000 00000000 0000D000 8EDA223C1537BECA93FCEA8A37B78CF50 linker
    03-31 05:55:52.480 1822-1197/? A/google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview W/google-breakpad: 5.178
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview W/google-breakpad: 5178
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview W/google-breakpad: cdb4c4c9-8331-4c87-8ff8-592d3515cb6c
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
    03-31 05:55:52.591 857-1197/com.example.android.webview A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x6d4d4f90 in tid 1197 (mali-renderer)
    03-31 05:55:52.607 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: property debug.db.uid not set; NOT waiting for gdb.
    03-31 05:55:52.607 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: HINT: adb shell setprop debug.db.uid 100000
    03-31 05:55:52.607 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: HINT: adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039
    03-31 05:55:52.665 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    03-31 05:55:52.665 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'hardkernel/cm_odroidxu3/odroidxu3:5.1.1/LMY49F/00799280db:userdebug/test-keys'
    03-31 05:55:52.665 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '256'
    03-31 05:55:52.665 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
    03-31 05:55:52.666 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: pid: 857, tid: 1197, name: mali-renderer  >>> com.example.android.webview <<<
    03-31 05:55:52.666 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x6d4d4f90
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     r0 6b8e6020  r1 00000001  r2 fffffffd  r3 00000004
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     r4 00000000  r5 aed588dc  r6 00000001  r7 a01ced68
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     r8 aa87b0a7  r9 00000000  sl ffffffff  fp aec4be00
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00000000  sp a01ced30  lr aa87a88f  pc 6d4d4f90  cpsr a0000010
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000d4f90  [anon:libc_malloc]
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0027488b  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
    03-31 05:55:52.798 2839-2839/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0004be04  [anon:libc_malloc]
```

Comment: What is the exception stack trace?

Comment: I have added the crash report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exception happens in the native code, there isn't much you can do in your Java code about it. Seems to be a graphic memory exhaustion, as it is crashing in malloc called from the GL library code. You say that the WebView is never destroyed, perhaps this is a result of memory fragmentation (the graphics code allocates / frees memory, and finally the memory map becomes so fragmented, that it's not possible to find a contiguous block of the requested size). I would suggest considering destroying and recreating WebView from time to time.

Also, it seems that this crash report is from a CyanogenMod rom. Do you have the same problem when using genuine Android builds?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, i have an odroid with cyanogemod 5.1.1. It doesnt occur with stock android on a "normal" smartphone.
Can you explain me, why the chrome browser can handle this crash and the app doesnt?
Thank you

Comment: Because Chrome usually runs GPU-related code in a separate process. So when it crashes, the main Chrome app process is not affected and continues to run. But in WebView everything is within a single app process, so crash in one component brings down the whole app.

Comment: OK. Thanks for this information. My conclusion is that i cant do anything if a website in the webview do crazy things. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, if it's heavy on graphics, then the only thing you can try is deleting and recreating WebView from time to time.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is still a problem but I recently encountered a similar problem on a Samsung device with Mali GPU and it turned out to be a piece of ES6 code running in WebView (namely an arrow function). Once I changed it to use ES5 'function' keyword, the error was no longer happening.

If this is still a problem for you, I'd suggest checking for use of any ES6 syntax and changing it to ES5 syntax or use Babel.

Might be an issue with ES6 interpreter within Chrome/Chromium WebView.