# crash android app after update chrome version 76

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, crash

my android application suddenly crashed a lot.

[crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeYHH.png)

All error logs contain libGLES_mali.so.

It mainly occurs on Galaxy s7, Galaxy s7 edge, Galaxy Note FE, and it seems that the GPU is using Mali-T880.

How can I avoid this crash?

Comment: It seems similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329467/android-chromium-webview-crash

Comment: @emandt i already read that. We are already using babel and ES6.

Comment: Try to use ES5 and check the result. Unfortunately your issue seems an error on Android, Driver/Kernel or something so deep, so it cannot solved easily.